# Primefaces DatePicker Range Selection with Time

Tags: primefaces, datepicker, daterangepicker

We use a [DatePicker](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/datepicker/datePicker.xhtml?jfwid=0572b) component in our project. Primefes Version 10.

```html
<p:datePicker id="range" selectionMode="range" showTime="true" />
```

Period selection works great:

[image]

The selected period will be deleted when I change the time.

[image]

Is it possible to use Date Range Picker with a Time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently that is not available but has been requested on GitHub.  I suggest you go upvote the issue there.

See Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5037